# CSS Help - float

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am having a tough time fixing a small issue. I am little embarrassed in asking help for this CSS issue but a different set of eyes might help fix this.

**ISSUE**

1. Go to http://ajaxtown.com/uranium/
2. Extreme top you will find a bar (telephone number and social icons and search)
3. Now resize the window (mobile size)
4. Again maximize it to full width.
5. You will see the search icon coming down.

**RESOLUTION**

1. While experimenting with firebug, i found that if you inspect element on the search icon, you will find the below css.

   ```
   .top-search {
      float: left;
      width: 40px;
   }
   ```
2. If i uncheck float and then again check it, everything gets fixed. The search icon gets aligned with the social icons.

But I am not able work this out.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Please let me know if I am not clear with my question.**

Saha

Comment: firefox gave me no error, chrome does!!
why don't you apply float to `social-icons top-social-icons`

Comment: I have already applied float:left to that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it this way:

In CSS:

```
//Before

.top-search {
  float: left;      
  width: 40px;
}

//after

.top-search {
  display: table;      
  width: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I placed the search into the `.social-icons` div

```
<div class="social-icons top-social-icons">
    <a href="http://twitter.com/username" class="twitter" rel="external"><i class="icon icon-twitter"></i></a><a href="http://www.facebook.com/username" class="facebook" rel="external"><i class="icon icon-facebook"></i></a><a href="http://ajaxtown.com/uranium/?feed=rss2" class="rss" rel="external"><i class="icon icon-rss"></i></a>
    <div class="top-search">
        <a class="top-search-bt open" href="#">
        <i class="icon"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quick fix

Comment: Weird, works for me in Chrome. All I did was drag `div.top-search` into `div.social-icons` in developer tools.

Comment: Any luck @AbhishekSaha?

Answer (score 1):

That works for me on Chrome (Canary)

```
<div class="social-icons top-social-icons">
    //social icons here
    <a class="top-search-bt open" href="#"><i class="icon"></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS fix

.topbar-right .topbar-right-inner {

```
border-right: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
width:163px;
```

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{

```
.topbar-right .topbar-right-inner {
    border-right: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

}

Comment: This did work. But the problem is i cannot hardcode the width. Because the social icons are configurable. Which means users can add/remove the social icons. Thanks anyways.